# axios get response is junk

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using axios to fetch some data from typicode api.
The result I am getting is some junk like this.

[image]

// apis.js

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getRequest = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    console.log(res.data);
}
getRequest();
```

I am running this code using command `node apis`.

I am expecting result as below, as shown mentioned at `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Is there more code in `apis.js`? if yes, then can you please share that as well? there might be something else that is giving the incorrect response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is completely fine and works on my machine. This must be a problem with your environment. Are you inside a VPN of a company or make this call from a server that sits in a special network or anything like that?

Comment: Yes, there is a company VPN, I disconnected from VPN and it worked fine. How come VPN affecting this?

Comment: Your company does all the networking configuration in the VPN. Very often they define policies to improve security (like blocking certain webpages) but from my experience very often the configuration is not ideal which leads to weird errors like yours.